# firefox browser application runtime environment

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, b2g

In Firefox browser, 
when I write an app, Can I think this application runs on the runtime environment xulrunner?

On the other hand, does this mean on the firefox browser, the runtime environment is xulrunner? is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox uses Gecko, that in Firefox is embedded inside xulrunner.

In Firefox OS, XUL is not used.